# CMake search path

Tags: pcl, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS installation somehow sets CMake the search path to point to favor ROS packages in /opt/ros.
I want find_package(PCL) to choose the version in /usr/lib rather than /opt/ros/groovy
(The ROS version is missing all of the Grabber stuff)
How can I prevent this behavior? Is there some environment variable I need to set?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64456/cmake-search-path/) by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake uses the environment variable [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) to specify the search path for all find_*() commands.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on 2013-06-13**:
What variable or file does ROS modify when it gets installed, which adds it to the front of the search path? CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is unset on my machine.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-13**:
When you source the setup.bash/sh these environment variables will be set.